# Node.js Hapi route path

Tags: javascript, node.js, routes, hapi.js

I need to match the following route on a Hapi server:

```
http://localhost:8080/messages/{deviceId}/?deviceType=phone
|___________________||________||_________||_______________|
           1              2          3            4
```

Detail:

- 1 is my **server url**
- 2 is the **path**
- 3 is a parameter called **deviceId**, that is going to be different according to the requests.
- 4 is a **query parameter** that is attached by the emitter of the request. I do not control this attached query parameter, however I know it's always going to match *?deviceType=phone*.

I tried to do as following, but the Hapi server doesn't even start..

```
server.route({
    method: 'POST',
    path: config.serverPath + '/messages/{deviceId}/?deviceType=phone',

    handler: (request, reply) => {

    }
});
```

Then I tried this:

```
server.route({
    method: 'POST',
    path: config.serverPath + '/messages/{deviceId*2}',

    handler: (request, reply) => {

        const parameters = request.params.deviceId.split('/');
        const deviceId = parameters[0];
        const attachedQueryParameter = parameters[1]; // should match '?deviceType=phone'
    }
});
```

`{deviceId*2}` means that the route will match only if 2 parameters are provided.
I can then easily extract the parameters.

This route nearly works, expected when the parameters start with a '?' (error 404)...
... which is exactly the case I want to match (component n° **4** of the request starts with '?').

Can anyone help me with this tricky problem? Thanks

---

Tried again and still have a 404 error... My path is set to:

```
path: config.serverPath + '/messages/{deviceId}'
```

It works if I do a POST with this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/messages/7d8a09d37d1e7b?deviceType=phone
```

But if I do a POST with this one:

```
http://localhost:8080/messages/7d8a09d37d1e7b/?deviceType=phone
```

It doesn't work... 404 error, saying 'Not found'.
I'm using hapi v15.0.1.

---

I found a temp. solution with this path:

```
path: config.serverPath + '/messages/{deviceId*}'
```

It works for both requests above, but with the second one the request.params.deviceId contains a '/' character at the very end...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the path to

```
path: config.serverPath + '/messages/{deviceId}'
```

and use `request.query` to get the query parameters.

Comment: I tried this already, and I'm having a 404 error with this route if I do the following request : http://localhost:8080/messages/658734-2384635-373/?deviceType=phone

Comment: But the route is working if I remove the "/" between the path parameter and the query parameter: localhost:8080/messages/658734-2384635-373?deviceType=phone

Comment: It works for me.
Remember that your endpoint is implemented as a POST. If you request the endpoint with a GET method, it will give you 404.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way. No need to write cofig.serverPath. Also, you will have to use Joi for validation of query params.

```
path: '/messages/{deviceId}',
handler: storyController.getAllPaginatedStories,
config: {
    validate: {
        query: {
            deviceType: Joi.string().required().valid(['phone']),
        }
   }
}
```